# keytool the term is notrecognised in android studios

Tags: android-studio

keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2

- keytool -list -v -keystore E:\3rd year\Sem V\sed\key store path\maps ...
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```